# compare first column of 2 file : while second have 2 column but first have one column

Tags: awk, grep

i have 2 file :

file 1:

```
abc
mno
pqd
```

file 2:

```
ump 10
abc 12
sfg 30
klp 45
mno 21
pqd 32
jkl 98
lkg 45
```

I want output like this:

```
abc 12
mno 21
pqd 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `join` :

```
# join  <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
abc 12
mno 21
pqd 32
```